# The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing

Our Sliverlight application (using V2.4) make a call to custom GP Toool which executes huge process which last for more than 10 min (avg), but before that client gets timed out. After going through all forums. a) Increased executiontime out value b) Increased GP Tool client timeout values but nothing worked. Any best methods to find the root cause. In Fiddler we are getting timeout exception in stack trace.

Below is the exact message from fiddler tool

Server Error in '/ArcGIS/rest' Application.

---

Request timed out. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Note : URL is available and able to browse in REST.This is an post request.

Please help on this

Comment: isn't your ArcGIS Server logging any errors during the request? Also, a request this long should be made asynchronously and its status checked using something like checkJobStatus (JS API). Then you shouldn't see the same timeout

Comment: @tomfumb ArcGIS server does not log any error. We are using asynchronous call only. It works in REST but not from client application. The error message says just remote server returned an exception.

Comment: I could see an entry in restlog.txt like this  : 11/8/2012 6:06:40 AM ERROR:Thread was being aborted. :: at ESRI.ArcGIS.REST.GPServer.SubmitGPTaskJsonFormatter.Init()
 at ESRI.ArcGIS.REST.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest()
 at ESRI.ArcGIS.REST.RestHttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 http://server1/ArcGIS/rest/services/CustomTools/GPServer/CustomTool/execute?dummyGeom={"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolyline","spatialReference}...

Comment: Issue has been resolved by myself. Posted solution in http://gisprog.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/error/

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue and answer is here http://gisprog.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/error/